# Settings menu in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Hello I'm making a web page where I want a menu option and I was wondering what is the best way to approach this. I saw in W3 that the `<menu>` tag is not supported by any major browser (which is news to me) and I don't think the `<select>` tag is appropriate for a situation like this. I'm sure there is a pretty simple way of doing this with javascript but it's been awhile since I've done extensive web programming so I'm a little rusty on it.

What I want is a general settings option for the page, a lot like the 3 bar menu at the top right of the Chrome browser, or the general option menu for any browser for that matter. I want an option that can handle many things (theme change, user profiles, show/hide features on the page, ect.)

Comment: What do you mean you want a menu option? Can you show us an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: what exactly about the <select> tag don't you like?

Comment: What I want is a general settings option for the page, a lot like the 3 bar menu at the top right of the Chrome browser, or the general option menu for any browser for that matter. I don't like `<select>` because it seems like it should be used for most specific purposes. I want an option that can handle many things (theme change, user profiles, show/hide features on the page, ect.)

Comment: @rsayles3, you should clarify your question by editing the question itself, rather than writing comments.

Comment: Just to clarify: the `menu` element is universally supported, but just as it has always been in HTML: effectively a synonym for `ul`. The new semantics (and syntax) proposed in HTML5 drafts is something completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways in web to design menu i.e css, jquery, javascript, html li-ul.

Basically all of them required ul-li html tags. but to give look and feel and cachy slik look and different effects to menu as per page theme, we may requried to choose css and jquery.

[sample CSS menu](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/05/css-menu-and-navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do this, a simple Google search might help you. Search terms like "HTML menu" or "CSS menu" should get you going. But using an HTML unordered list combined with CSS styling might do the trick for you, and may be the easiest to implement. A `<select>` could work, or there are things like jquery, etc.

[Turn unordered list into menu](http://stochasticmatrix.com/FAQs/CSS1.html)

[jquery menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at jQuery for that.

Esay enough and great result.

http://jqueryui.com/menu/